# Run job repeatedly, but with no overlap and not at precise scheduled times

Tags: cron

I have a background task that needs to be run repeatedly, every hour or so, sending me an email whenever the task emitted non-trivial output.

I'm currently using `cron` for that, but it's somewhat ill-suited: it forces me to choose exact times at which the command is run, and it doesn't prevent overlap.

An alternative would be to run the script in a loop with `sleep 3600` at the end of each iteration but this then needs extra work to make sure the script is always restarted after boot and such.

Ideally, I'd like a cron-like tool where I can give a set of commands to run repeatedly with approximate execution rates and the tool will run them "when convenient" and without overlapping execution of different iterations of a command (or even without overlapping execution of any command).

Short of writing such a tool myself, what would be the recommended approach?